# Positivity of a limit

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R$. Show that if $f(x)>0$ for all $x$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)$ exists, then $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x)\geq0$.

**My attempt:** 
Let $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x)=l$. By definition this means that for all $\epsilon>0 $ there is $\delta>0$ such that $|x-0|<\delta$ implies $|f(x)-l|<\epsilon.$ Hence, $f(x)-\epsilon <l<f(x)+\epsilon$.

Can we make $\epsilon$ very small, so that $\epsilon<f(x)$ (then  0<$f(x)-\epsilon <l$), which is what we wanted to prove?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prove by contradiction. Suppose $L=\lim_{x \to a} f(x) <0$. Let $0<\epsilon <-L$. Then, for $|x-a|$ sufficiently small we get $|f(x)-L| <\epsilon$ which implies $f(x) <L+\epsilon <0$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Since $f(x)>0$, $-\epsilon<f(x)-\epsilon$. You have shown that for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists $x$ such that $-\epsilon<f(x)-\epsilon\leq l$ implies $l\geq 0$.

Comment: but since $\epsilon>0$, then $-\epsilon<0$, so $()−$ can be negative too, no?

Comment: A number which is superior to every negative number is positive, if not, $l<0, l<{l\over 2}<0$.